# How to group by DATE only in column datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a problem with grouping in SQL Server Express 2005

I have a `DATETIME COLUMN` but i want to group it only by date.

Here my SQL Statement:

```
SELECT (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [FullName],d.user_id,CONVERT(varchar,d.log_date,101) AS log_date, min(d.login_time) as LOG_IN, max(d.logout_time) as LOG_OUT, sum(d.totaltime) as TOTHrs 
FROM tbldtr d INNER JOIN tblUsers u ON d.user_id = u.User_Id
WHERE d.user_id = 'ADMIN1' and d.log_date BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND '6/15/2013'
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, log_date), 0),u.FirstName,u.LastName,d.user_id order by d.log_date asc
```

but it give me this error:

> **Column 'tbldtr.log_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.**

Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Especially on SQL Server, [you shouldn't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  This actually applies to _all_ variable-precision values (in all languages), but that blog has details on SQL Server's special gotchas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move `convert(varchar,d.log_date,101)` into `group by` clause:

```
select
    u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName as [FullName],
    d.user_id,
    convert(varchar, d.log_date, 101) as log_date,
    min(d.login_time) as LOG_IN,
    max(d.logout_time) as LOG_OUT,
    sum(d.totaltime) as TOTHrs 
from tbldtr d
    inner join tblUsers u on d.user_id = u.User_Id
where d.user_id = 'ADMIN1' and d.log_date between '20130601' AND '20130615'
group by
     convert(varchar, d.log_date, 101),
     u.FirstName, u.LastName, d.user_id
order by log_date asc
```

Also, it's more safe to change dates in the `where` into unambiguous format - `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: it's really strange, try to remove `order by` to see what's happening

Comment: it works!! I removed the `order by`. Thank you! you save my day!

Comment: you can just change `order by d.log_date` (as in your code) to `order by log_date asc` (as in my code) or to `order by 4` (not recommended since order of columns may be changed later)

Comment: Strange that you still get the error. Try `group by 1,2,3` in @Roman Pekar code. This either work or we're searching at the completely wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the casting function so it should become something like:

```
GROUP BY CAST(d.log_date AS DATE)
```

Comment: thank you but it give me this result: **Type DATE is not a defined system type.**

Answer (score 0):

if you move `convert(varchar,d.log_date,101)` in group by then result will not be right as it will count both date and time so when you have more then one entry in same date with different time it will show two time in result.

try this it will work

```
SELECT ( u.firstname + ' ' + u.lastname ) AS [FullName], 
       d.user_id, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, cast(d.log_date  as DATE) , 101) AS log_date, 
       Min(d.login_time)                  AS LOG_IN, 
       Max(d.logout_time)                 AS LOG_OUT, 
       Sum(d.totaltime)                   AS TOTHrs 
FROM   tbldtr d 
       INNER JOIN tblusers u 
               ON d.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE  d.user_id = 'ADMIN1' 
       AND d.log_date BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND '6/15/2013' 
GROUP  BY cast(d.log_date  as DATE),
          u.firstname, 
          u.lastname, 
          d.user_id 
ORDER  BY d.log_date ASC
```

Comment: it give me this result: **Type DATE is not a defined system type.**

Comment: which SQL Server vresion are you using ??

Comment: **SQL Server Express 2005**

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the following:

```
SELECT (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [FullName],d.user_id,CONVERT(varchar,d.log_date,101) AS log_date, min(d.login_time) as LOG_IN, max(d.logout_time) as LOG_OUT, sum(d.totaltime) as TOTHrs 
FROM tbldtr d INNER JOIN tblUsers u ON d.user_id = u.User_Id
WHERE d.user_id = 'ADMIN1' and d.log_date BETWEEN '6/1/2013' AND '6/15/2013'
GROUP BY (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName), d.user_id, CONVERT(varchar,d.log_date,101)
order by d.log_date asc
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but still it give me the same result.